# How to apply cubic spline interpolation over long Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I need to replace missing data within pandas Series using cubic spline interpolation. I figured out that I could use the `pandas.Series.interpolate(method='cubic')` method, which looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create series
size = 50
x = np.linspace(-2, 5, size)
y = pd.Series(np.sin(x))

# deleting data segment
y[10:30] = np.nan

# interpolation
y = y.interpolate(method='cubic')
```

Although this method works just fine for small series (`size = 50`), it seems to cause the program to freeze for larger ones (`size = 5000`). Is there a workaround?

Comment: This seems to be a `Memory Error`.  Are you using a 32-bit machine?  Or a 32-bit version of Python, for that matter?

Comment: this is really strange!

Comment: I'm using a 64-bit machine with the last 64-bit version of the WinPython distribution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pandas` calls out to the `scipy` interpolation routines, I'm not sure why `'cubic'` is so memory hungry and slow.

As a workaround, you could use `method='spline'` (scipy ref [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline)), which with the right parameters, gives essentially (seems to be some floating point differences?) the same results and is dramatically faster.

```
In [104]: # create series
     ...: size = 2000
     ...: x = np.linspace(-2, 5, size)
     ...: y = pd.Series(np.sin(x))
     ...: 
     ...: # deleting data segment
     ...: y[10:30] = np.nan
     ...: 

In [105]: %time cubic = y.interpolate(method='cubic')
Wall time: 4.94 s

In [106]: %time spline = y.interpolate(method='spline', order=3, s=0.)
Wall time: 1 ms

In [107]: (cubic == spline).all()
Out[107]: False

In [108]: pd.concat([cubic, spline], axis=1).loc[5:35, :]
Out[108]: 
           0         1
5  -0.916444 -0.916444
6  -0.917840 -0.917840
7  -0.919224 -0.919224
8  -0.920597 -0.920597
9  -0.921959 -0.921959
10 -0.923309 -0.923309
11 -0.924649 -0.924649
12 -0.925976 -0.925976
13 -0.927293 -0.927293
```

Comment: I can't find any docs about the `s=...`, but it seems that the interpolation will not make any sense if we don't pass that value. What is that?

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni the docs for `s` are at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep - basically a higher s value makes for a more smooth spline.

Comment: `s = 0.0 (interpolating) if no weights are supplied.` Thanks. It means that this example use pure interpolation.